# POWER BI: Show the Value from a Cell with a measure : using Dynamic Index || Count Dax Formula?

Tags: powerbi, numbers, row, return-value, lookup

I have a table of power market which contains a column of Daily Return called "LN" (Sort Descending).

I have written a measure which has given me the specific number of the row containing the value I need to know on column LN. This number can change because of the period chosen.

```
Scenario VAR = ROUNDUP((0.95)*COUNT('GFI German Base power M1'[LN]),0)​
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOXqv.png)
Here for instance I want from the Report View find the row 86 of the Column LN.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpKD1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruNx2.png)

I tried to create a system of Index but some number of the order is missing when I move the slicer of the period from the report view.

I tried these formulas but no luck .

```
Ln order = RANKX( ALL('GFI German Base power M1'), 'GFI German Base power M1'[LN], , ASC, Dense)
```

```
IndexColumn = COUNTX(FILTER('GFI German Base power M1', 'GFI German Base power M1'[LN] <= EARLIER('GFI German Base power M1'[LN])), 'GFI German Base power M1'[LN])
```

Can any one please suggest me with a solution.

Best,

Romain.A

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are far away to find the solution, I suggest to create a calculated column in the 'GFI German Base power M1' table using the rankx function but if you want the period slicer to work you should not include the ALL() in the expression. This may work:

> Ln order = RANKX( 'GFI German Base power M1', 'GFI German Base power
> M1'[LN], , ASC, Dense)

After that you can add in the filter pane of the visual card a condition for Ln  order being 86.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I tried and it didn't change the result. I Finally worked out on something tricky that worked. Will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally come up with something by my own. Please find the answer below.

```
VAR_95 = CALCULATE(SUM('GFI German Base power M1'[LN]),TOPN(([Scenario VAR]),'GFI German Base power M1',[LN], ASC))-CALCULATE(SUM('GFI German Base power M1'[LN]),TOPN(([Scenario VAR]-1),'GFI German Base power M1',[LN], ASC))
```